# Infinite .sh file Python

Tags: ubuntu, sh, infinite

So I'm running a discord bot on an Ubuntu os and need to do an infinite loop .sh file

This is my windows .Bat file. when the bot goes down it will restart

```
:1
py bot.py
goto :1
```

I have tried this in ubuntu .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while:; do python3 ./Bot.py ;done;
```

But i get this error:

```
bash: ./Bot.sh: /bin/ban^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Help would be great!

Thanks All!

Comment: there needs to be a space between the while and the : (although the particular error is related to what hellow said)

Answer (score 1):

There is a windows new line (`\r\n`) in your first line of the script, hence the error

> bash: ./Bot.sh: /bin/ban^M: bad interpreter

The `^M` indicates a windows newline.
Try the tool `dos2unix` to convert alle line endings to unix newlines `\n`.